# Could not parse query

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I have tried rewriting this query a few different ways, but with no luck. Help here is much appreciated.

```
function createWaterBodyDropDown(region) {

    var query = "SELECT 'LAKE_NAME' FROM 1IfQgRAeKPbVJwEpAnqqpYlN8sgiPMg1VQ_RyArI WHERE 'REGION'=" + '"' + region + '"';

    var queryText = encodeURIComponent(query);
    var gvizQuery = new google.visualization.Query(
        'http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=' + queryText);


    //Send query and draw table with data in response
    gvizQuery.send(function (response) {
        var str;
        var numRows = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows();
        var numCols = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfColumns();

        var name = [
            '<label style="font-weight:bolder;font-size:16px">Water body: </label>' + '<select id="waterbody_menu"  style="font-size:16px;" onchange="select_waterBody(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">' + '<option  value="">--All--</option>'
        ];

        for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
            var val = response.getDataTable().getValue(i, 0);
            name.push("<option value=" + "'" + val + "'" + ">" + val + "</option>");
        }
        name.push('</select>');
        document.getElementById('waterBody_container').innerHTML = name.join('');

    });

}
```

Comment: you put your columns `LAKE_NAME` and `REGION` inside single quotes, but your region value used in your SQL inside double quotes, so your SQL string ends up looking like: `SELECT 'LAKE_NAME' FROM 1IfQgRAeKPbVJwEpAnqqpYlN8sgiPMg1VQ_RyArI WHERE 'REGION'="foobar"`  Is this deliberate, or will it cause any problems?

Comment: Hi, yes that was deliberate... I have also tried writing this query as follows:                                                            var query = "SELECT LAKE_NAME FROM 1IfQgRAeKPbVJwEpAnqqpYlN8sgiPMg1VQ_RyArI WHERE REGION=" + region;
var query = "SELECT LAKE_NAME FROM 1IfQgRAeKPbVJwEpAnqqpYlN8sgiPMg1VQ_RyArI WHERE REGION=" + '"' + region + '"'; I am guessing that goolge has changed their api.

Answer (score 0):

Your column names have no special characters so they don't need to be quoted, though they could be (with single quotes). String values must be quoted with single quotes. See the [reference manual](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/sql-reference#Select) for more details.

So:

```
SELECT LAKE_NAME FROM 1IfQgRAeKPbVJwEpAnqqpYlN8sgiPMg1VQ_RyArI WHERE REGION = 'foobar'
```